# How to "press a key" in a minimized window

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

So, im playing this silly game on which when you press the key 'e' you grab all the itens nearby. First i was just using this command so it did it "automatically".

```
@echo off  
pause  
:loop   
nircmd wait 3000
nircmd sendkeypress e
goto loop
```

but this implies that the game window always have to be on the top of all windows, but sometimes i want to grab these itens with the window minimized so i tried using this line

```
@echo off
:loop
nircmd wait 3000
nircmd win sendmsg ititle "gamename" 0x45 0 0
goto loop
```

In case you never heard of it, nircmd is a little cmd-addon you can download.
The 'win sendmsg' command reference says this: *Send a message to the specified window. The 3 values in [Additional Parameters] specifies the message parameters: Msg, wParam, lParam.*

But, it isn't working and I have no idea why. Is there any way i can do it just using cmd?

I'll link [here](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/win.html) the Nircmd - Command Reference in case I didn't made it clear

Comment: cant you set the needed window on focus?

Comment: try [sendKeys.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat)  . It accepts the window name as a first argument and the second is the keys you want to send.It can be used for programs that are not on focus.

Comment: Sendmsg will talk to the win api, IIRC to send keystrokes you need 0x102 and wparam the dec ascii val  lower case e being 101. So try `nircmd win sendmsg ititle "gamename" 0x102 101 1`

Comment: How is this question linked to tag [tag:spring-batch]??

Comment: OOh thanks a lot. did work